# Using regex detect special string and replace only a part of it

Tags: java, regex

I'm having a bit of a hard time phrasing this question so I was unable to find an answer to it. Also, it may be that there is no simple method to do what I'm trying to do, which is..

I'm trying to detect a special sequence, in my case a `;` followed by a number, and replace the `;` with `&#` followed by the same number. For example:

```
;123;;234; ;345; --> &#123;&#234; &#345;
```

Regex can easily **find** my sequence, but how can I keep the number to use in the replacement?

Of course using a separate `replace` for every digit will work, but I'm looking for something a little more elegant than this:

```
str = str.replace(";1","&#1");
str = str.replace(";2","&#2");
...
str = str.replace(";9","&#9");
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In other words you want to replace `;` with `&#` only if there is digit right after it. In that case you can use [look-ahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html#lookahead) mechanism like

```
str = str.replaceAll(";(?=\\d)","&#");
```

`;(?=\\d)` means exactly what I described earlier: accept `;` ONLY if there is `\\d` after it, but do not include this `\\d` in match so only `;` part will be replaced.

Comment: This is EXACTLY what I was looking for. Clear, concise. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

Maybe like this, untested. Check the Javadoc:

```
str = str.replaceAll( ";(\\d+)", "&#$1;" );
```

Comment: The `;` is unnecessary as the regex isn't set to detect it. Otherwise, this works. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the regex you need

```
String s =";123;;234; ;345;";  
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(";(\\d)");
Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
while (m.find()){
  s= s.replace(";"+m.group(1), "&#"+m.group(1));    
}
System.out.println(s);
```